# Python: plotting free fall with drag

Tags: python

[image]

[image]

I have to model an object that is in free fall with air resistance. Above are pictures with the code and of the graphs.

Top graph: x (position) against t (time)
Middle graph: v (speed) against t
Bottom graph: a (acceleration) against t

Problems:

- The velocity keeps increasing pretty fast even though the acceleration is roughly 0. The velocity should eventually become constant since acceleration will eventually be 0 and stay zero since the gravitational force is equal to the drag force.
- The acceleration becomes rougly 0 eventually but it is not exactly 0, even though mathematically it should become 0 and stay 0 once the two forces are equal to each other.
- You would expect the height to decrease much faster. From these outputs, you are still at 20000 m after 200s.

I can't figure out why the velocity doesn't eventually stay constant and how the acceleration can exceed 0?

Here are relevant equations that I have used:

[image]

Note: I used Newtons second law to find the expression for the acceleration (line 24)

Fnet = ma = -mg + C * rho * A * v^2

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please copy-paste your code rather than using an image. Also, the statement "even though mathematically it should become 0" is incorrect. The number will approach 0 as time approaches infinity, but mathematically never actually reaches 0 for finite time.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The acceleration should however become exactly 0? Time doesn't have to approach infinity. Since a = 0 if Fnet = 0, which is when the gravitational force is equal to the drag force (C*rho*A*v^2). (I also don't really know how to insert code with proper formatting)

Comment: see the [help center](/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting. generally, check out the guide to [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your graphs seem correct.  If we expand the timespan to 600 seconds se note:

- Interestingly the acceleration crosses zero before t == 100
- Acceleration decreases from a positive value, but never becoming zero before reaching the ground (i.e. Altitude = 0)
- Thus, terminal velocity is not reached (but has a max of -157.8027 at 31.8 seconds

**Code**

```
mass = 120  # kg
g = 9.81    # m/s/s
c_1 = 1.2
rho_0 = 1.2
h_n = 10400
area = 1
dt = 0.01     # reduce delta t to improve computation speed (result not impacted)
t = np.arange(0, 600, dt)  # extend time to 600 seconds

x = np.zeros(len(t))
v = np.zeros(len(t))
a = np.zeros(len(t))
rho = np.zeros(len(t))

x[0] = 39000
v[0] = 0
a[0] = -g

for i in range(1, len(t)):
    rho[i] = rho_0 * np.exp(-x[i-1]/h_n)
    a[i] = -g + c_1*rho[i]*area*(v[i-1]**2)/mass
    v[i] = v[i-1] + a[i-1]*dt
    x[i] = x[i-1] + v[i-1]*dt
```

**Charting**

```
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3,1,sharex=True,figsize=(8,12))
    
ax1.plot(t, x)
ax1.set(ylabel = 'Altitude (m)')
ax1.grid()

ax2.plot(t, v)
ax2.set(ylabel = 'Velocity (m/s)')
ax2.grid()

ax3.plot(t, a)
ax3.set(ylabel = 'Acceleration (m/s/s)', xlabel = 'Time (secs)')
ax3.grid()
```

**Charts**

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much! Do you know why it makes such a huge difference to evaluate based on previous states rather than the forward method?

Comment: @Stallmp -- actually I'm making a correction to this answer shortly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I just realized that the initial graphs may be physically/mathematically correct, since I realized that the air density increases over time since the height also decreases, resulting in a constantly increasing air resistance, so a terminal velocity doesn't have to be attained. So there should be nothing wrong with my initial code actually right?

Comment: @Stallmp - correct as indicated by my updated answer.  I realized my initial code was incorrect (above code fixed the issue).

Comment: Thank you very much! So the problem with the initial code was that the acceleration and rho should also have the -1 right?

Comment: @Stallmp -- actually your original code may be equivalent to my code.  I did my version since I thought it was clearer to i-th value of a, v, and x was being updated based on the i-1 value of these items in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

**The acceleration becomes rougly 0 eventually but it is not exactly 0, even though mathematically it should become 0 and stay 0 once the two forces are equal to each other.**

Mathematically, the force of drag becomes arbitrarily close to the force of gravity, but is never exactly equal. This is a consequence of differential equations, which you should look up but can be explored in part [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Mechanics/quadvfall.html). In short, the limit of the acceleration as time approaches infinity is 0.

**The velocity keeps increasing pretty fast even though the acceleration is roughly 0. The velocity should eventually become constant since acceleration will eventually be 0 and stay zero since the gravitational force is equal to the drag force.**

The answer to this is pretty much the same as the previous: The velocity is never truly constant, but comes arbitrarily close to a value called the [terminal velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity). Given your numbers, the terminal velocity is about `40.4`.

**You would expect the height to decrease much faster. From these outputs, you are still at 20000 m after 200s.**

At a terminal velocity of `40 m/s`, after `200s` your ball would've fallen `8000m`. Obviously, since your item has yet to reach its terminal velocity, it has fallen a lot more. This is not too unreasonable; in a drag free world (with only gravity) your ball would take `89.21` seconds to fall to the ground, and the effect of drag is significant.

All that being said, there will obviously be some inaccuracies that can be reduced by reducing the size of dt.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications! However you would never expect the velocity to increase right? Only decrease less and less. Otherwise that would mean that the drag force exceeds the gravitational force which shouldn't be possible?